# Android Room fetch related entities with non-null embedded property

Tags: kotlin, android-room

This post by Florina  (https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1) introduced a nice way to simplify one-to-many queries, by defining a composite class

```
class UserAndAllPets {
   @Embedded
   var user: User? = null
   @Relation(parentColumn = “userId”,
             entityColumn = “owner”)
   var pets: List<Pet> = ArrayList()
}

@Transaction
@Query(“SELECT * FROM Users”)
List<UserAndAllPets> getUsers()
```

This allows you to fetch all users with their pets in a single query. However, it starts to get annoying when I have to null check `user` every time I am using it. Plus, I don't want query to return a `UserAndAllPets` object without a user. Is there anyway I can enforce this rule in query, instead of doing a safety check whenver I am using `UserAndAllPets`?